# Symfony search form without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I use symnfony and have form for search entity by parameters, but when submit form my page reload, I don't know how realized search form when fill out fields and under form I have result without reload page, like write in filed some word and in this time under update block with result

this my form with action, action wait get parameters and rendering in this view with form and result

```
    <div class="filters" id="filter_form">
    <form action="{{ path('outbound_invoices') }}" method="get">
        <div class="choice-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn active">
                <input type="radio" name="status" value={{ status_draft }} checked="checked">{{ status_draft|trans }}
            </label>
            <label class="btn">
                <input type="radio" name="status" value={{ status_sent }}>{{ status_sent|trans }}
            </label>
            <label class="btn">
                <input type="radio" name="status" value={{ status_paid }}>{{ status_paid|trans }}
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="choice-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn active">
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="all" checked="checked">all
            </label>
            <label class="btn">
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="contract">contract
            </label>
            <label class="btn">
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="other">other
            </label>
        </div>

        <input name="search" id="filter-employees" placeholder="{{ 'search'|trans }}" class="form-control">
        <p>from Date: <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_datepicker" dataformatas="dd-mm-yyyy"></p>
        <p>to Date: <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_datepicker" dataformatas="dd-mm-yyyy"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
// block result
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            {% trans %}invoice_number_short{% endtrans %}
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {# @var outboundInvoice \AppBundle\Entity\OutboundInvoice#}
        {% for outboundInvoice in outboundInvoices %}
        <tr class="clickable" data-href="{{ path('outbound_invoices_show', {'id': outboundInvoice.id}) }}">
            <td>
                {{ outboundInvoice.invoiceNumber }}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in action I just create query builder for find entities and rendering in template. How it's realized with ajax without reload and search in real time ?

Comment: You should read up on Ajax.

Comment: I know but I not have experience with js and ajax, I understand action return json and how work with this json I don't know, maybe some example would help for me

Comment: Just google "get started with ajax" and you will find a bunch of tutorials. Specially since you're already seem to use jQuery. SO isn't the correct place for those.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to post your form via ajax with jQuery:

```
var form = $('#my-form');

$.post(
    form.prop('action'),   //action url
    form.serializeArray(), //serialized form data
    function(result){      //callback
       console.log(result);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the AJAX as you'd normally do:

```
//add jquery here
$('#filter-employees').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        action:"/invoices"
        //...
    }).done(function(resp));
});
```

Then in the controller action, you need to verify if the request is a XMLHttpRequest one, and create the functionality accordingly.

```
/**
 * @Route("/invoices", name="outbound_invoices")
 */
public function processAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        //do work
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('whatever');
}
```

OBS: I would recommend you to use Angular for this type of things.